# How can I use Hibernate validation on <s:file> tag in Struts2?

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I have an input form with:

```
<s:form action="myaction" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   ...     
   <s:file label="Picture" name="img" /> 
   ...
   <s:submit value="Send" />
</s:form>
```

How can I return error if user don't insert an image (it's a required field)?
I'm using Hibernate validation (@NotEmpty, @NotNull, ecc..), but I don't know if it's possible validate a file input field.

Comment: What exactly do you want to validate? Variable in your Entity with @NotNull or variable inside your action?

Comment: @AleksandrM The corresponding entity attribute is String type (in the DB is stored the picture's path), but users upload pictures from the <s:file> tag in JSP.. In the action I take the File object, I store it in a server directory, and then I save the path in the Entity. So, I just need validation in the action (on the File object). I know that it's possible to valide also non-entity attributes (in the action) using the same annotation, but I don't know if there is an annotation that validate File type (NotNull or NotEmpty are used for String, Max for Integer, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could validate File object for `null` with Struts2 `required` validator http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/required-validator.html.

Additionally `@NotNull` accepts any type, not only Strings http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html.

Comment: I use already Hibernate validation for other fields, so it's impossible to use Struts 2 validation also (only one validation is allowed). 

By the way, I tried with @NotNull on the File image definition in the action, but it not works, it gives me NullPointerException because image is null!

Comment: I tried also to put @NotNull on the imageFileName definition.. nothing change!

Comment: See this link http://code.google.com/p/full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2/wiki/2_Hibernate_Validator_integration.

Comment: Your statement "so it's impossible to use Struts 2 validation also (only one validation is allowed)" is wrong.

Comment: I read from http://code.google.com/p/full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2/wiki/2_Hibernate_Validator_integration that defaultStackHibernate and defaultStackHibernateStrutsValidation uses only Hibernate validation, basicStackHibernate uses no kind of validation.. so, how can I use the two type of validation together?

Comment: Can't you put both interceptors inside your stack?

Comment: You're right! I thought it wasn't possible, so I didn't try. Thank you!